# Tkinter Back button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter app where I created many classes for my frames since I have different pages. I also have classes for my data to help with managing it. I wanted to add a 'back button' which would show the previous frame.
To do so, in my main window class, I created a back button and assigned it with a function. And everytime I change frames, I change a parameter of my main frame : previous and current. These variables store the frame objects themselves.
Here's an example (from within an data class function, with fen being the main window):

```
fen.projView.forget()
fen.precedent = fen.projView
###
self.comView = CommandeFrame(fen,self)
self.comView.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='nwse',padx=10,pady=10)
fen.actuel = self.comView
```

And here is my back funtion:

```
def retour(self):
    self.actuel.forget()
    self.precedent.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='nwse',padx=10,pady=10)
    self.actuel,self.precedent = self.precedent,self.actuel
```

I tried printing the values of 'precedent' and 'actuel' and get the correct frames. But for some reason, they don't actually change inside the window, pressing the button only swaps them instead of hiding one and showing the other before swapping. (I also tried without the swapping and get the same result)

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Try changing `self.actuel.forget()` to `self.actuel.grid_forget()`.

Comment: ohh that works thanks!! What does that actually change? I've been using forget for the rest of my code and it works fine @acw1668

Comment: If you call `print(self.actuel.forget)`, you will get something like `<bound method Pack.pack_forget of <tkinter.Frame object .!frame>>`.  It means that `self.actuel.forget` is an alias of `pack_forget` function, not `grid_forget` that you need actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @acw1668, the answer to this was simply replacing `.forget()` by `.grid_forget()`.
I am however still using `forget()` in the rest of my code without problem.